# save many property of modelview data in database mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model view of my product which have to many property and i want to save it in database with entity framework.But the easy way is using this code :

```
public void NewProduct(NewProductModel viewModel)
{
   var dbModel = repository.FindProductById(viewModel.id);
   dbModel.Model = viewModel.Model;
   dbModel.Brand = viewModel.Brand;
   dbModel.Cost = viewModel.Cost;

   //its' too many

   repository.AddProduct(dbModel);
   repository.SaveChange();
}
```

But the property is too many.
are you have better way to reduce this code?

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way, but if you want to iterate over a generic set of properties, you can take a look at [msdn reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)

Comment: thanks but please edit link and remove ] from end of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for this or (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration).

Here's a short example:

```
// Make sure you check out the documentation before copy/pasting this
// code and using it as it's not the proper way of using automapper
public void NewProduct(NewProductModel viewModel)
{
    var dbModel = repository.FindProductById(viewModel.id);

    // If the properties have the same names already then AutoMapper can do it automatically
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
      cfg.CreateMap<NewProductModel, YourDBModelType>());

    // Otherwise you use can create your own mapping rules
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
      cfg.CreateMap<NewProductModel, YourDBModelType>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Model, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Brand))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Cost, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cost)));


    // mapping
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var dbModel = mapper.Map<YourDBModelType>(viewModel);

   repository.AddProduct(dbModel);
   repository.SaveChange();
}
```

You can find more info in the documentation section on the [github repo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection)

Comment: where mapper comes from ? i mean in mapper.Map